# How to create "self-adjusting" bookmarks for tkinter text box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox, bookmarks

I'm creating a function-specific text editor using tkinter. I would like to add a bookmark capability, and have seen several examples of using .yview()[0] or .index(INSERT) to get the yview first line number or actual line number of the line to which the bookmark should be added. What I don't know is how to adjust the bookmark(s) based on line insertions/deletions to other parts of the text box. I'm using some great code that Bryan Oakley shared to create line numbers for a textbox. This code also provides a "proxy" function which allows for the creation of virtual events to handle different tkinter functions (e.g., insert, delete, replace, etc.) Here is the code (slightly tweaked to handle spacing for different font sizes):

```
class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None
        self.font_spacing = 0
        self.setfontspacing(self.font_spacing)

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def setfontspacing(self, spacing):
        self.font_spacing = spacing

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True :
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1] + self.font_spacing
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0].zfill(7)
            self.create_text(2,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum)
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a proxy for the underlying widget
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, *args):
        # let the actual widget perform the requested action

        cmd = (self._orig,) + args
        result=None
        try:
            result = self.tk.call(cmd)
        except Exception:
            pass

        # generate an event if something was added or deleted,
        # or the cursor position changed

#        print(cmd, args, "=>", result)

        if (args[0] in ("insert", "replace", "delete") or
            args[0:3] == ("mark", "set", "insert") or
            args[0:2] == ("xview", "moveto") or
            args[0:2] == ("xview", "scroll") or
            args[0:2] == ("yview", "moveto") or
            args[0:2] == ("yview", "scroll")
        ):
            self.event_generate("<<Change>>", when="tail")

        if (args[0] in ("insert", "replace", "delete") ):
            self.event_generate("<<Text_Change>>", when="now")

        # return what the actual widget returned
        return result
```

I've bound the Text_Change event to my custom text widget and it allows me to track changes (i.e., to see if changes have occurred and prompt for save on exit, etc.). So that part is working fine.

However, I don't know how to capture the details about lines that were inserted/deleted when these events occur. The   print(cmd, args, "=>", result) gives lots of details, and I guess I could figure out a way to calculate deltas based on that information, but it seems like a complicated solution.

I was wondering if anybody had tackled this problem before and might have suggestions. Or maybe there's just a much simpler solution that I'm overlooking.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Is your "bookmark" a way of moving a specific line to the top of the screen? Or should a bookmark belong to the text to let you jump to that line? Are you aware of the "mark" feature of text widgets?

Comment: Bryan - what I would like to do is associate a "bookmark" with a specific line of text in the text widget. Then be able to jump to that line using something like text.see() and text.mark_set(). I'm not necessarily concerned about moving it to the top of the screen. I haven't thought about "mark" yet. Would that automatically adjust the "bookmark" if text lines above it were inserted or deleted?  Thanks!  BTW - your line number code is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The text widget has the ability to set bookmarks via the `mark_set` command. Marks can be used just like a text widget index. For example, you could set a mark "footer" toward the end of a long file and then use the `see` method to make the footer visible.

Marks represent the gap between two indexes. If you set a mark at index "200.0", the mark represents the space between the preceding index and that index. The mark will "stick" to one side of the gap or the other. By default it sticks with the character to the right, but that can be changed with the `mark_gravity` method which accepts either "left" or "right".

Here is a contrived example that sets a bookmark at line 200, and then provides a button to jump to that mark. Notice that even after the program starts up, you can insert as many lines as you want and the mark will still be "stuck" to the word "This" (or more precisely, the letter "T").

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, height=20, yscrollcommand=lambda *args: vsb.set(*args))
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
jump = tk.Button(root, text="Jump to bookmark", command=lambda: text.see("bookmark"))

jump.pack(side="top")
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(300):
    text.insert("end", f"Lorem ipsum dolar set\n")
text.insert("200.0", "This line is bookmarked\n")
text.mark_set("bookmark", "200.0")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bryan - Thanks! This looks great and I believe it will do the trick! I can't believe I overlooked this type of solution. My bad. As always - appreciate your great feedback and solutions.